# Como utilizar o comando preg_match do PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

Como utilizo o `preg_match` para detectar uma string onde tem que começar com "/comando"?

Essa função, pra mim, é bem complicada de entender...

Queria detectar um /comando no inicio de uma frase e pegar o resto da string pra continuar o comando

Por exemplo:

> /falar teste1 teste2 teste3

Detectar o comando "/falar" e dizer "teste1 teste2 teste3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, se a sua variável que contem a frase começar SEMPRE com "/", eu digo, por exemplo, se o /comando não for a partir do 4º caracter, é possível fazer isso com a função `strpos`.

Um exemplo de funcionamento seria:

```
$var_texto = "/comando teste1 teste2 teste3";

// retorna true se $var_texto começar com /
if(strpos($var_texto, "/") === 0){
    $array_texto = explode(" ", $var_texto);
    $comando = $array_texto[0];

    // Remove o comando dos arrays
    unset($array_texto[0]);

    // Obtem a string final
    $continuacao = implode(' ', $array_texto);
}
```

Dessa forma você terá que o comando é `$comando`e seus parâmetros ficam em `$continuacao`

Comment: quase funcionou 100%! deu erro na linha do unset

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$array_texto' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '('

Comment: Opa. O que faltou?

Comment: era só a sintaxe:

unset ($array_texto[0]);

muito obrigado.. salvou legal!

Comment: Nossa, verdade. Editei a resposta. Vlw :)

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar também `preg_match_all`:

```
$var_texto = "/comando teste1 teste2 teste3";

if(preg_match_all('/(\/\w+)|(\w+\s\w).*/', $var_texto, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0][0], PHP_EOL; // -> /comando
    echo $matches[0][1], PHP_EOL; // -> teste1 teste2 teste3   
} else {
    echo 'Fora do padrão', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Regex:

```
(\/\w+)     -> captura a barra "/" e caracteres alfanuméricos até um espaço
(\w+\s\w).* -> captura caracteres alfanuméricos separados por espaço, tudo junto
```

[**Veja no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/DVi4JU)

Comment: Eu recomendaria ainda tratar o retorno da função no *if*, algo [assim](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SimpleWeakEditors), para garantir que o formato foi adequado, mas mesmo assim melhor que `explode`. +1

Comment: Muito bom. Obg!